# How to give a user "create any database" permission in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions

Is it different from the `dbcreator` permission?

Can anybody explain the process?

Answer (score 15):

The [Server-Level Roles documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188659.aspx) says:

> *Members of the dbcreator fixed server role can create, alter, drop, and restore any database.*

This obviously exceeds the ability to just "create any database" mentioned in the title of your question.

To add a login to the *dbcreator* role, use [`ALTER SERVER ROLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-server-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
ALTER SERVER ROLE dbcreator
    ADD MEMBER server_principal;
```

The process to grant only the permission `CREATE ANY DATABASE` is as simple as:

```
-- Must be in master to grant server-scoped permissions
USE master;
GRANT CREATE ANY DATABASE TO server_principal;
```

It is generally seen as best practice to grant only the minimum permissions required.